# Does a Pokémon Crystal game degrade after playing a lot?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I have an official Pokémon Crystal game and after playing more than 450 hours I see that my game is degrading, or I don't know why is this happening.

Imagine that I have a *Feraligatr* in the first place of my team, well, if I'm battling against a *Parasect* (let's say), and he does **thunder wave** the first turn always appears: *"It doesn't affect to Feraligatr"*.

But on the second turn the *Parasect* does the same movement and this time it affects to *Feraligatr*.

Is this supposed to happen? Or is it just a glitch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As strange as it sounds, you are not the first to encounter this. Someone else posted [on this forum](http://www.pokecommunity.com/showthread.php?t=106650) pretty much exactly the same thing as you - a Feraligatr in Gen II that has problems being hit with paralysis.

In any case though, I have a very good feeling this is not due to degredation. Something in the back of my mind is tickling that the phrase "it doesn't effect" implies that a move that does no damage but gives a status effect has missed, whereas "it didn't effect" implies that the target is immune to the move. I'm guessing that's the best answer here, but I thought they fixed the "100%-accuracy moves are actually only 99.6% accurate" problem in Gen II.

Either way, this is a minor problem that I do not believe is indicative of any technical issues.

Answer (score 5):

The only things that  usually "degrade" in a gameboy cartridge during a normal lifetime are the battery and the electrical contacts. The [battery will eventually die](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_line#Cartridges) causing a loss of all save data and the ability to save (the battery is apparently replaceable). The contacts can also corrode, which can make the game temporarily unplayable.

Nothing happens to the Random Number Generator, which is what you're describing here. Crystal, like almost all videogames, uses a pseudograndom number generator, and sometimes quirks in how numbers are generated appear; this can have effects like certain moves are more likely to take effect on certain turns in the battle due to certain predetermined sequences of numbers. If you're seeing anything at all, odds are it's a quirk of the PRNG.

Sometimes games have long, preset strings of pseudorandom numbers that are generated at certain times like when the machine is turned on; in many early games (like the Pokemon Trading Card game) this is noticable if you savestate and repeat an action; "random" actions like coin flips will always occur in the same sequence if you restart from the same savestate.